# How can I create an angular service for use in different modules?

Tags: angularjs

I see in the angular documentation for [creating services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services) that a service is created by definining a factory on a module.

However I need to define a common service for use across multiple modules.
I am not seeing any thing in the documentation for that. Can it be done? Or is there some way to access a service from a module other than the module it was created on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check working demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vu7has2h/).

Define a service in some common module like:

```
angular.module('mySharedModule', [])
     .service('mySharedService',...
```

Then in other modules, use

```
angular.module('myModule', ['mySharedModule'])
    .controller('mySharedService', function (mySharedService) {
    ...
```

Then you can use `mySharedService` inside the module `myModule`. Your service is now injectable to it.

Comment: When you say .service did you mean .factory?

Comment: Oh, `service` and `factory` are both `providers`. In some sense they are for the same purpose. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory

Comment: This does not seem to work. I have in one JS file the module angular.module("treeApp")
    .controller("treeCtrl", function($scope, ... Then in another JS I define a factory service called Tags (the shared service) on that module with angular.module("treeApp").factory("Tags", function($http) ... Finally I have a new module called exportApp I want to refer to Tags. I define it like angular.module("exportApp", ["treeApp"]).controller("exportCtrl", ["Tags", function(Tags){}]. But I am getting uncaught errors

Comment: Your fiddle works as is, but when I replace service with factory it doesn't. Mine are defined as factory. Is there any way to get it to work with factory?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vu7has2h/2/. Just the syntax difference. I think you can try some examples of service/factory first.

Comment: That worked, thanks. (Corporate proxy prevents me from going to chat, so I will say a public thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

A service has to belong to a module. However, to use it in other modules, just include the owning module in the modules where you would like to use it. Example:

```
angular.module('common', [])
    .factory('yourService', ...);

angular.module('yourModule', ['common'])
    .controller('yourController', ['yourService', function(yourService) {
       // common service available here.
    }]);
```